# Adding currents with transistors

Tags: transistors, current-source, buffer

I was wondering if it's possible to add currents with transistors (or other active devices) like we can add voltages with op-amps. Importantly, the currents need to be added in such a way that the two inputs are isolated from the output, so that there is no loading (there would have to be a low input resistance, and a high output resistance).

I couldn't find any information on the internet. If such contraption exists, a schematic would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, op-amps add currents and, as a result of certain resistor values, the output voltage is a representation of that current.

Comment: It's possible to make a [multi-emitter bipolar transistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-emitter_transistor), and these were made by the millions as components in classic TTL logic chips. However they are AFAIK unavailable as discrete devices.

Comment: @Andyaka It's more like opamps don't admit currents (apart from bias current which can be compensated and offset current) and thus you can turn current imbalances into an output voltage that will compensate the current imbalance at 0V scaled through a resistor.  The addition of the currents happens outside of the opamp.

Comment: @user107063 it should be obvious that when I said op-amp I meant an op-amp in a fairly bog-standard circuit. In other words, an op-amp without a power supply does nothing useful and, the addition of any signals requires a linear circuit. This implies an op-amp circuit. I don't know if you were trying to be pedantic because it doesn't help anyone.

Comment: It'd be nice if you'd make a block diagram of what you're trying to implement. Are your input signals more accurately represented by a current or a voltage?

Answer (score 2):

In general, current sources in parallel add (within compliance voltage limits of each). You could think of this as analogous to voltage sources in series.

Said current sources might be implemented with op-amps and transistors, Howland current sources, current regulator diodes or whatever.

If those current sources are voltage-controlled there need not be much loading on the input voltages.

For example, one design of 4-20mA output has a 0-16mA current source in parallel with a fixed 4mA current source.

Comment: How would you create current sources with op-amps and resistors? I have been trying to figure that out to no avail.

Comment: @KKZiomek “Howland” is the magic search term to add, but ones with transistors have significant advantages for unipolar current sources or sinks.

Answer (score 1):

The op amp stage known commonly as a voltage summing amp can also be seen as a current summing amp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAViYz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The op amp feedback maintains the potential between its input terminals at zero, so the -ve input pin is at 0V, like the +ve. This is the virtual ground. The current at the point labelled is therefore the sum of the input currents:

I1 + I2 = V1/R1 + V2/R2

The current through Rf is equal and opposite, so

Vout = -Rf * (V1/R1 + V2/R2)

In other words, if you want to sum currents going to a DC reference point, you can apply that reference to the + input and connect your current sources directly to the negative input. The op amp will sum them for you (with inverted output), with a scaling factor determined by Rf. (Of course you must take care that your circuit has enough headroom for the expected output voltage, and so on.)

This does not meet your requirement that the output is isolated from the inputs, as both inputs must be referenced to the same DC point, but it is a method of summing currents actively.